# How to get the unique employee record with min date of birth?

Tags: sql, oracle

If Names field is duplicate then only one name should be fetched and in gender field if one name with male and another with a female then female should be fetched and If both the names having the same gender then lowest DOB should be fetched

```
INPUT:
NAME      GENDER DOB
--------- ------ -------
ABC       M      20-MAR-18
ABC       M      30-MAR-18
DEF       M      20-MAR-18
DEF       F      25-MAR-18
GHI       F      20-MAR-18
GHI       M      10-MAR-18
JKL       F      20-MAR-18
JKL       F      10-MAR-18

OUTUT:
NAME      GENDER DOB
--------- ------ -------
ABC       M      20-MAR-18
DEF       F      25-MAR-18
GHI       F      20-MAR-18
JKL       F      10-MAR-18
```

Comment: Hi there - when you post questions, could you please post what you've tried, and what your problem is, rather than simple "can you tell me how to do this?"  ...you should try some things first, and then if you have problems ask ...check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        p.*,
        row_number() OVER (partition by name order by gender, dob) as rn
    FROM Person p
) WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: I think I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function:

```sql
SELECT name, gender, DOB
FROM (
  SELECT name, gender, DOB, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
      PARTITION BY name -- Group by name
      ORDER BY gender, DOB -- Order by gender, DOB within each "name" group
    ) AS RowNumber
  FROM MyTable
) src
WHERE RowNumber = 1 -- Only get one row per group
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14d7a/8)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  name,
  min(gender) keep(dense_rank first order by decode(gender, 'F', 0, 1)) gender,
  min(dob) keep(dense_rank first order by decode(gender, 'F', 0, 1)) dob                   
from 
  emp
group by 
  name
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c2a24/4)